# What is the output when I cascade two amplifiers?

Tags: control-system

I have taken a circuit 'A'.
\$V_{\text{output}} = V_{\text{input}} e^{at}\$ for a constant input \$V_{\text{input}}\$. But now when I try to cascade two such circuits.

How can I find the final output?
My attempt was to find transfer function of 'A', TF=\$ \frac1{S-a}\$. Since it was cascaded, final TF=\$ \frac1{(S-a)^2}\$. And inverse was found to be \$V_{\text{output}}=V_{\text{input}}t e^{at}\$.
This answer did not make sense because until \$t>1\$, output of cascade is smaller, also I am not sure if I can take transfer function like that.

Comment: Are you able to assume that your amplifiers are LTI (linear and time invariant)?

Comment: Yes I guess, Its a cross coupled pair @ThePhoton

Comment: Cant one just substitute Voutput1, the output of stage 1 as Vinput2, the input of stage 2 to get Voutput2 = Vinput1*(e^(at)) * (e^(at)) = Vinput1*((e^(at)) ^2) ? So, basically, the same shape, but sharper rise when it does rise.

Comment: When the definition of the system contains the absolute time, it is probably a time **variant** system. Have you proven that the system is time invariant?

Comment: "*for a constant input Vinput.*". What is the output of the system when the input is varying? Please specify that since, when we cascade two such systems, the second system recieves a varying input.

Comment: "*for a constant input Vinput.*". So \$e^{(at)}\$ is probably the **step** response of the system. The transfer function is the Laplace transform of the **impulse** response of the system. Please show is how you got \$1/(s-a)\$ as the Laplace transform of the impulse response of the system.

Comment: Thanks, basically if step response is 1/(s-a), then impulse function is 1/(s(s-a)) and therefore the final output is product of step response of 1st circuit and impulse response of second circuit?@AJN

Comment: impulse function is s/(s-a) *

Comment: Yes, I think so. Would that solve the problem of "*...answer did not make sense because until t>1, output of cascade is smaller...*" ? If the stages in a cascade amplifier are modelled as dynamic systems, then there can be time instances where the output of the second stage is smaller than the output of the first stage.